# Inheritance and extensions in Swift

Tags: inheritance, swift, covariance

How do [inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) and [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) interact in Swift ? In more detail, are extensions defined for superclasses automatically available for subclasses? In that case, isn't there a variance issue (e.g., if the extended type shows up as a return type in the extension) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance and extensions interact as you would expect.  Given two classes `Foo` and `Bar` such that `Bar <: Foo`, methods available in Foo and extensions to Foo are available to Bar.  As for the variance issue, subclasses may override methods and provide more specific return types.  For example, here is `Bar` overriding `baz` with a covariant type

```
class Foo { 
    func baz() -> Foo {
        return Foo()
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    override func baz() -> Bar {
        return Bar()
    }
}
```

---

Methods in extensions cannot be overridden yet, but the same principles apply.